# Matrix Decomposition of Hat Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, matrices

Can anyone tell me how could i proof this equation:

$ \widehat {Ab} = A^{-T} \hat b A^{-1}$

with the condition: $det(A)=1$

Also, How this equation change when $det(A)\neq1$

This is Exercise 2.4 of book: An Invitation to 3-D Vision-From Images to Geometric Models

by S. Shankar Sastry.

Exercise 2.4 (Skew-symmetric matrices). Given any vector $w = [w_1, w_2, w_3] \in R3$, we
know that the matrix $\hat w$ is skew-symmetric; i.e. $\hat w^{T} = -\hat w$. Now for any matrix $A \in R^{3\times3}$ with determinant $det(A) = 1$, show that the following equation holds:

$ A^{T} \hat w A =  \widehat {A^{-1}w}$

Then, in particular, if $A$ is a rotation matrix, the above equation holds.

Hint: Both $A^{T} \widehat {(.)}A$ and $\widehat {A^{-1}(.)}$  are linear maps with $w$ as the variable. What do you need in order to prove that two linear maps are the same?

Comment: What exactly is $\hat x$?

Comment: $\hat x$ is hat operator which convert cross product into inner product. like: $\hat a.b $ = cross (a,b)

Comment: Ehsan, that reply doesn't really make sense.  Are you saying that we can consider $a\times\cdot$ as a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $\hat{a}$ is defined to be the matrix representing this operator?

Also, what is $A^{-T}$?  Does that mean `A inverse transpose'?

Comment: Both $A^{T} \widehat{(.)} A$ and $\widehat {A^{−1}(.)}$ are linear maps with $w$ as the variable.yes, $A^ {-T}$ mean A inverse transpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $b$, we have
\begin{align*}
\widehat {Ab} = A^{-T} \hat b A^{-1}
&\Leftrightarrow A^T \widehat{Ab} A = \widehat{b}\\
&\Leftrightarrow y^TA^T \widehat{Ab} Ax = y^T\widehat{b}x \ \text{ for all } x,y\\
&\Leftrightarrow y^TA^T (Ab \times Ax) = y^T(b\times x) \ \text{ for all } x,y\\
&\Leftrightarrow (Ay)\cdot (Ab \times Ax) = y\cdot(b\times x) \ \text{ for all } x,y\\
&\Leftrightarrow \det(Ay,Ab,Ax) = \det(y,b,x) \ \text{ for all } x,y\\
&\Leftrightarrow \det\left(A(y,b,x)\right) = \det(y,b,x) \ \text{ for all } x,y\\
&\Leftrightarrow \det(A)\det(y,b,x) = \det(y,b,x) \ \text{ for all } x,y,
\end{align*}
and the last statement is true because $\det(A)=1$.

In general, if $\det(A)\neq0$, we have $\det(B)=1$ where $B=\det(A)^{-1/3}A$. Therefore we have $\widehat{Bb} = B^{-T}\widehat{b}B^{-1}$. For any $z=(u,v,w)^T$, since
$$
\widehat{z}=\pmatrix{ 0 &-w & v\\ w & 0 &-u\\ -v & u & 0},
$$
we have $\widehat{\lambda z}=\lambda\widehat{z}$ for any scalar $\lambda$. Therefore, by pulling out the factor $\det(A)^{-1/3}$ from $B$ (and $\widehat{Bb}$), we get
$$\widehat{Ab} = \det(A)A^{-T}\widehat{b}A^{-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You started from equation $\widehat {Ab}Ax = A^{-T}\hat bx$. Could you please let me know where this equation come from?

Comment: @Ehsan Just move the $A^T$ and $A$ to the left and multiply by $x$.

Comment: I know,But i thought that i should start with $\widehat {Ab}$ and obtain $A^{-T} \hat bA^{-1}$. it's clear now,Thank you for your answer

Comment: user1551, i understood from your proof that if i want to prove that two linear maps are the same i should show that their inner and cross product on the same variable are same.is it correct?

Comment: It's somthing like that, but not exactly as what you say. Instead of linear maps, we consider *bilinear forms* $B_M(x,y) = y^TM^T\widehat{Mb}Mx = (My)\cdot(Mb\times Mx)$. We actually want to prove that $B_A=B_I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Two bilinear forms are identical if and only if they always evaluate to the same value for any $x$ and $y$, i.e. $B_A=B_I$ iff $B_A(x,y)=B_I(x,y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Escuse me User1551, Why you say that $B=det(A)^{-\frac13}A$ . are you factored A from $det(A(x,y,b))=det(A)^{3}det(x,y,b)$ ?

Comment: @Ehsan No, we define $B=\det(A)^{-1/3}A$ so that $\det(B)=1$.